# Atom python-debugger: How to change the current file

Tags: python, atom-editor

I use Atom for Python, and I use python-debugger for debugging. If I use alt-r to open the debugger in a particular file, then open it in a different file it still only runs the first file for debugging. Is there a command or something I can use to switch which file I want to debug? Currently I just close Atom and make sure to open the debugger in the desired file the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I had this question too! When I tried restarting Atom and then opening the debugger again as you suggested, I noticed a welcome message in the debugger console that said to use `e=filename` to debug a different file.

In the field labelled "Enter debugger commands here", type `e=filename` for whatever file you want to debug, then hit enter and continue debugging as usual. For example, if I wanted to debug `hello.py`, I would type `e=hello.py`.

[image: Atom python debugger]